# Angular 8 routerLink translating incorrectly

Tags: angular

New to Angular, working through a Udemy course. Here is the relevant part of my template component:

```html
<a
   class="list-group-item"
   *ngFor="let user of users"
   routerLink="['/users', user.id, user.name]"
   >
   {{ user.name }}
</a>
```

And here is how the link is rendered:

```html
http://localhost:4201/users/%5B'/users',%20user.id,%20user.name%5D
```

It's only happening on this one component. I have `routerLinks` elsewhere that work fine. I can actually get the user.id and user.name to render correctly by `{{ interpolating }}` them, but the rest of the link is still wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you need the brackets around routerLink with this syntax.

Comment: @Phix bingo. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks a lot.